# Kibana visualization - Customize legend labels

Tags: kibana, kibana-6

I have a stacked bar chart, split by a boolean field.  This causes the legend to appear with two colours (cool!) but the legend has these values: true and false.  To the reader, there is no context for what is true or false means.

[image]

In this case, the field name is `is_active`.

At the very least having the field name appear in the legend will help people read and understand the chart.

Better:  Is there a way to replace "true" and "false" with "Active" and "Inactive" respectively?

I tried this Advanced->JSON Input:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "doc['is_active'].value ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Which results in an error "String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number".  If I replace the strings in the JSON Input with numbers, the numbers do indeed appear in the legend.  No help though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using `term aggregation` in `split series` bucket, use `filter aggretation`. Create two filters, one for `true` and one for `false` and apply custom labels there.